# Differences using the slash in the server terminal or server terminal with GUI

Tags: command-line, 18.04, directory, gui, execute-command

I have installed the 18.04 LTS server version. I did different commands like:

```
tar -xzf xxxx.tar.gz xxxx/ (without GUI)
hadfs dfs -put input /input (with GUI)
```

I did other commands which work with folder too.

However, after this, I installed a GUI using:

```
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

However, with the GUI installed and using the terminal, some of these commands which work with folder 'change' and maybe I do not need to put the initial or final slash or put it.

My doubt is: why sometimes without the GUI that command is correct and with the GUI the use of the slash change? Maybe is because the GUI that I installed? Or is it a basic noob fail because of my lack of knowledge with Linux systems?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say but see the `man pages` for those commands! I don't think the desktop has something to do with this behaviour!

Comment: For instance, when I run the tar command before installing the GUI, it worked fine, but after, it didn't work. The difference in that command is that slash.

Comment: Was this done on the same folder when done in the GUI?

Comment: Yes, I am in the same folder and I have done all the same steps. This is why I do not understand if maybe this is because the GUI modifies something, some mistake of mine because I am very 'noob' with Linux...

Comment: This command `tar -xzf xxxx.tar.gz xxxx/ (without GUI)` should be `tar -xzf xxxx.tar.gz`, you are extracting not creating!

Answer (score 0):

I see an error in your command. This `tar -xzf xxxx.tar.gz xxxx/` ought to be `tar -xzf xxxx.tar.gz`. To create a compressed tar file you use:

```
tar -zcvf xxxx.tar.gz xxxx/
```

And uncompressing on an already existing folder will simply overwrite it not produce an error. If you intended to uncompress it into a destination folder thenn the command would be:

```
tar -C xxxx/ -xzvf xxxx.tar.gz
```

**Note:** The `z` is superfluous when used in extracting as `tar` can determine the right decompression algorithm to use.